# Finding $GCD$ excluding some elements from an $array$

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

I have an array of numbers. I want to calculate $GCD$ of all numbers but excluding numbers from particular index $a$ to index $b$.
I need to repeat the same operation multiple times with different values of $a$ and $b$.
Is there any better way other than the obvious $Brute Force$ one?

Comment: You can use a segment tree structure. It can be built in O(n log n) time and a query time will be O(log n).

Comment: Any useful link to learn use of Segment Tree for this problem? Really appreciated.. :)

Comment: This is the first link I found using Google: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/.
When you'll get the basic idea just replace sum operation with GCD one.

Comment: The idea of a segment tree seems more suited to organizing the GCD's of subintervals `[a..b]` rather than the GCD's of their complements (excluding the subintervals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the GCD of (integer?) array elements `c[1..n]` excluding `c[a..b]` is the GCD of the two values, GCD of `c[1..(a-1)]` and GCD of `c[(b+1)..n]`.

So if you formed the (descending) sequence of GCD's of the initial segments `c[1..k]` and those of the terminal segments `c[m..n]`, you would be able to find all the queries of GCD's excluding some intervening segment `c[a..b]` in constant time (taking the GCD of two previously computed results).

Comment: Thanks man! Saved me from unneccesary hustle of segment trees(which doesn't seem to be valid for this problem).
I populated two arrays one forward and another backward for segments as your described above and then answered queries in O(1) :)